# Make Image follow Mouse, pointing towards a set point

Tags: javascript, css, mouse, mouselistener

i'm looking for a way to have a image follow the mouse pointer, pointing towards a certain point.

[image: illustration showing concept]

This Illustration shows the Mouse Pointer in 2 positions and how i would like to have the image following the mouse pointer to behave.

The Red Arrow is the image i want to show following the mouse pointer, the green ring represents one axis of the position of the red arrow, the blue line pointing towards the target represents the second axis of the arrows position as well as the rotation of the Red Arrow (making it not only be inbetween mouse and target, but also pointing correctly to the target).

I was easily able to find instructions on how to make an image follow the mouse pointer, but for the changes of positioning, i was struggling to find even the correct wording to find any results

Can anyone help me with this? what keywords could help me get on the correct path?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
not exactly a change for the original question, but a somehow related second question for a similar style:

[image: illustration with rotated mouse cursor]

This would be a similar situation, but instead of an image following the mouse pointing towards a point, the mousepointer itself would rotate to show the direction of the target

Comment: see: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event), [rotate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate()), and [trigonometry](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/trigonometry/)

Comment: thank you for the links, especially the first one. i will take a deep dive on that, as i feel my questions sometimes aren't as good as they could be. for the other topics, thank you very much, i will take a look as well

Comment: But also, here is a related question: [How can I rotate a css cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60443228/13762301), and an accompanying [codepen](https://codepen.io/addison912/pen/MWwmpoz)

Comment: thanks to your hints i was able to achieve what i wanted. https://codepen.io/hergi/pen/vYyZQNM  im sure there are some issues that could be handled better, but i wanted to post my rough code anyways for any googlers that might find this post